# Web application in Apache cannot access another web application on the same server running on localhost?

Tags: angular, apache

We have an Angular application running on Apache. This needs to access services from a backend application. This is a Java application running on localhost:9090

[image]

The website loads but on pages with backend calls, i'm seeing CORS errors:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9090/cord/titlesAuthors/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

I searched and SO.. there are several posts about CORS but most of them refer to localhost within Apache.

- The site is running on Apache (on CentOS 8, VM) at http://cordboard.info.
- The page http://cordboard.info/papers internally calls a service at  http://localhost:9090/cord/titlesAuthors
- The service is also running on the same VM and can also fetch data if i do a `curl -v  http://localhost:9090/cord/titlesAuthors`
- Not sure where i am going wrong.. public site works, service individually works.

**Questions:**

1. If needed, i can change the ip and port for the backend application. What should it be? Thought since the angular application needs to only access the backend localhost would be fine (backend not needed to be public).
2. Is there something we should do on Google Cloud VM's network / rules /  firewall?

**Our setup:**

1. Google cloud platform - VM (static ip <-- website domain has an A record)
2. Apache configs

```
/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/cordboard.info.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site.com
  ServerAlias site.info
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/html
  ErrorLog /var/www/site.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/site.com/log/requests.log combined
  <Directory "/var/www/site.com/html">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

3. Backend application running as a service on localhost

```
sudo systemctl status cord-java

...
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cord-java.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-05-20 21:42:39 UTC; 32min ago
```

Comment: If you send the client (webbrowser) an HTML page with a URL with localhost in it, that means access the webserver on the client's machine. You have a logic problem in how you are creating URLs in your HTML pages.

Comment: I will update my question. www.site.com -> VM's  static ip -> Apache, which is serving the site. The data within some html pages, needs to make calls to services to fetch/show data.

Comment: The CORS error is referencing this URL from the page you sent the client browser: `http://localhost:9090/cord/titlesAuthors/` You should not do that. You are instructing the browser to access that URL which is NOT your server.

Comment: Update my question with more details. The site is running on Apache (on CentOS 8, VM) at http://cordboard.info. The page http://cordboard.info/papers internally calls a service at  http://localhost:9090/cord/titlesAuthors . The service is also running on the same VM and can also fetch data if i do a `curl -v  http://localhost:9090/cord/titlesAuthors`. Not sure where i am going wrong.